# gatsby build → WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I'm using [gatsby-plugin-breadcrumb](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-breadcrumb/) to create a breadcrumb list.
Since I want to display the breadcrumb list on a page that is not the root page, we place the `Breadcrumb component` in `layout.tsx` as shown below.

```js
const Layout = ({ location, crumbLabel, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main>
        {location.pathname !== "/" && (
          <Breadcrumb
            location={location}
            crumbLabel={crumbLabel}
            crumbSeparator=""
            crumbstyle={{ color: "#666" }}
            crumbactionstyle={{ color: "#333" }}
          />
        )}
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

This code works fine in `gatsby develop`, but when I run `gatsby build`, I get the following error.

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.715s
 ERROR #95313 
Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"
See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html
  22 |         <Header />
  23 |         <main>
> 24 |           {location.pathname !== "/" && (
     |                     ^
  25 |             <Breadcrumb
  26 |               location={location}
  27 |               crumbLabel={crumbLabel}
  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
  - layout.tsx:24 
    demo/src/components/layout.tsx:24:21
  - extends.js:8 
    [demo]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/esm/extends.js:8:1
  - static-entry.js:263 
    demo/.cache/static-entry.js:263:20
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Can I put the `Breadcrumb component` in `layout.tsx` and hide the `Breadcrumb component` in the root page?

---

I also tried to hide it by getting the pathname in the useEffect.

```js
const [root, setRoot] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname === "/") setRoot(true)
}, [])

return (
  <>
    <Header />
    <main>
      {!root && (
        <Breadcrumb
          location={location}
...
```

As a result, the following error message was displayed.

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.510s
 ERROR #95313 
Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"
See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html
  35 |   var _useBreadcrumb = (0, _useBreadcrumb2.default)({
  36 |     location: (0, _extends2.default)({}, location, {
> 37 |       pathname: usePathPrefix ? location.pathname.replace(new RegExp("^" + usePathPrefix), '') : location.pathname
     |                                                                                                           ^
  38 |     }),
  39 |     crumbLabel: crumbLabel,
  40 |     crumbSeparator: crumbSeparator
  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
  - click-tracking-crumb.js:37 
    [demo]/[gatsby-plugin-breadcrumb]/components/click-tracking-crumb.js:37:107
  - extends.js:8 
    [demo]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/esm/extends.js:8:1
  - static-entry.js:263 
    demo/.cache/static-entry.js:263:20
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` `props` is only available in top-level components (pages). So if for some reason, you are reusing `Layout` component elsewhere and you are not providing (or it's not available) the `location`, it will break your code.

In your case, it seems that you are not providing the `location` at the `404` page. You can bypass it adding a default value such as:

```
const Layout = ({ location="", crumbLabel, children }) => {}
```

Or adding a condition like:

```
    {location && location.pathname !== "/" && (
      <Breadcrumb
        location={location}
        crumbLabel={crumbLabel}
        crumbSeparator=""
        crumbstyle={{ color: "#666" }}
        crumbactionstyle={{ color: "#333" }}
      />
    )}
```